# laravel query builder how to only retrieve year and month from dateTime field

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

i want to select only month and year from dateTime field in database i tried this

```
$historyMonth = App\Models\HistoryCostEstimation::where('user_id',$id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->toDateString('Y-m')->get();
```

but it isn't working is there any suggestion ?

Comment: You want this always or in some cases ? and what are the concerned fields ?

Comment: i always need it , and the concerned field is 'created_at' it's the dateTime field

Comment: So you can add a getter for the created_at field in `HistoryCostEstimation` like this `public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date)
{
    return Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('Y-m');
}` without changing anything in the query `App\Models\HistoryCostEstimation::where('user_id',$id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()`

Comment: And in the loop, if it will return more than one record you will just do `record->created_at` !!

Comment: Is it working for you ??

Comment: yep , it worked thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you always want that format you can define an `Accessor` in the `HistoryCostEstimation` model like this :

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($date) { 
    return Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('Y-m'); 
}
```

And you can query the records without any transformations :

```
App\Models\HistoryCostEstimation::where('user_id',$id)
                                  ->orde‌​rBy('created_at','de‌​sc')
                                  ->get();
```

Comment: i'm really sorry i was away for a while , thanks a lot for your effort
it works now thanks